# external script google site visualisation

Tags: google-sites

I have a google site. I want to use an external script to make google visualisations work on my site:

This is the piece of script that goes wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I added this script trhoug a htmlbox and i get the error:
**1+13 - 42: failed to load external url jsapi**

Why won't itthe jsapi load?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't load external site/page (even google pages) within HTML Box gadget.
To do so, you can create a custom gadget in Google Gadget Editor(using your gmail account),by visiting the following URL,
  http://www.google.com/ig/ifr?url=gge.xml

and you can put the above code there and save it,you will get url by right click and copy link  in the right side file name.Then, in your google sites page,
  Edit Page --> Insert --> More Gadgets --> Add Gadgets By URL --> Paste the URL copied above and save.